# Tokenizing an input file in c

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

I am trying to implement a simple program to seperate each word in a file. This is my first time using strtok(), so I am trying to create something simple to see how it works. However, I cannot get the code to work properly.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* tokenize(char *tempPhrase);

int main (void)
{

    FILE *in;
    char file_name[] = "test1.txt";
    char buffer[100];
    char *tokens = malloc (100 * sizeof (char));
    int i;

    chdir("./DataFiles");
    if (( in = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", file_name);
            return 0;
    }

    fgets(buffer, 100, in);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    *tokens = tokenize (buffer);

    for (i = 0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
            printf("%s\n", tokens[i]);
    }

    return 0;
 }


 char*  tokenize(char *tempPhrase)

 {

    char *search = " ";
    char *tempArray = malloc (20000 * sizeof (char));

    int i = 0;
    tempArray[i] = strtok(tempPhrase, search);

    while(tempArray[i] != NULL)
    {
            i++;
            tempArray[i] = strtok(tempPhrase, search);
    }


return tempArray;
}
```

I am getting the following errors/warnings when I try to compile:

```
fopen.c: In function ‘main’:
fopen.c:28: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
fopen.c:30: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
fopen.c: In function ‘tokenize’:
fopen.c:45: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
fopen.c:47: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
fopen.c:50: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Why would the strtok() function make tempArray an integer? This is causing all sorts of problems throughout the program and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You should not just "get rid" of the warnings, but correct the errors and **observe** the warnings and change your code to be correct. The messages are quite clear: You use the wrong types.

Comment: I have made a few corrections, but I cannot figure out why strtok() is making tempArray an integer.

Comment: This is no debugging service. Read the messages and check the lines mentioned. No idea what you mean with "making `tempArray an integer`.

Comment: The warning I am getting "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" is on the strtok() line. My understanding is that strtok returns a char*, so why would the assignment make an intenger from pointer?

Comment: You are **trying** to make an `int` from a pointer. Which type does `tempArray[i]` have??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems in your code that I can see:

`char tokens = malloc (100 * sizeof (char));`

This line you `malloc` something that isn't a pointer, it should be `char* tokens` at least.

That should get rid of a few

`fopen.c:28: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer`

warnings

You did the same again in your `tokenize` function.

Then a `malloc` should always be followed by a `free` call, to release the memory you've used.  Otherwise you have a leak.

So somewhere you need to call `free(tokens)` when you're done with it.  Same for your second `malloc` call.

Per the `strtok` documentation you should call `strtok` with its first parameter `NULL` if you want it to continue tokenizing from where it left off.

So `tempArray[i] = strtok(tempPhrase, search);` should really look like this

`tempArray[i] = strtok(NULL, search);`, for it to continue tokenizing the string you originally passed it.

Your `tempArray` init should be more like this

`char** tempArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));`  //init the first array

The reason you need `char**` is because you want an array of strings, and a string in C is represented by a `char*`, so now you need a pointer to an array of `char*` which is the `char**`

Those are only some of the issues I can see, without actually trying to compile your code.

[Here is a version of your program that compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ae0fa73ae491390)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: 1 Question... how would I free tempArray if that is what I am returning?

Comment: You would free at the end of your program.